# Makefile Variable - Replace Whitespace in Variable

Tags: regex, shell, perl, grep, gnu-make

I am trying to:

1. Export the path to a `.env` file so that it is accessible to `make`
2. In my `Makefile`, read the contents of the `.env` into a variable
3. Parse the contents out into variables that I will use to build and deploy my application

The problem is:

- I can't seem to find a regex to match on the spaces that `make` replaces my newlines with in order to parse out my variables. My regex is getting the right starting point, but includes the remainder of the `.env` file, rather than stopping at the whitespace after the value I want to extract.

I understand that when I `cat` my file into a variable, `make` strips newline characters. From [GNU Make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function):

> The shell function performs the same function that backquotes (‘`’)
>   perform in most shells: it does command expansion. This means that it
>   takes as an argument a shell command and evaluates to the output of
>   the command. The only processing make does on the result is to convert
>   each newline (or carriage-return / newline pair) to a single space. If
>   there is a trailing (carriage-return and) newline it will simply be
>   removed.

However, I can't get any regex to either recognize these spaces in a lookahead to extract my variables or replace these spaces with another character to aid in the extraction.

Example:

`.env`:

```
SSH_CREDENTIALS=path/to/my/key
ANOTHER_VAR=somethingelse
YET_ANOTHER_VAR=yetanothersomething
```

`Makefile`:

```
ENV_FILE_CONTENTS := $(shell cat $(ENV_FILE_PATH) )  # | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/x/g'
$(info $(ENV_FILE_CONTENTS))

SSH_CREDENTIALS := $(shell echo $(ENV_FILE_CONTENTS) | grep -o -P '(?<=SSH_CREDENTIALS=).*(?=[[:space:]])' )
$(info $(SSH_CREDENTIALS))

SSH_CREDENTIALS := $(shell echo $(ENV_FILE_CONTENTS) | grep -o -P '(?<=SSH_CREDENTIALS=).*(?=\s)' )
$(info $(SSH_CREDENTIALS))

[recipes below]
```

Command and result:

```
$ export ENV_FILE_PATH=./env/.env; make print_env_var
SSH_CREDENTIALS=path/to/my/key ANOTHER_VAR=somethingelse YET_ANOTHER_VAR=yetanothersomething # My .env file without the newlines
path/to/my/key ANOTHER_VAR=somethingelse # Attempt to extract the path to the SSH credentials fails (doesn't recognize whitespace lookahead)
path/to/my/key ANOTHER_VAR=somethingelse # Samething when trying \s instead of [[:space:]]
```

I've tried many other regexes and commands (`sed` to replace space with a character I can then target in the lookahead, etc.), with no luck.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure whether I fully understand what you are trying to do. But the contents of your `.env` file look like they could be included into you makefile directly, right? See [3.3 Including Other Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html).

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek - that seems to work. I had read about including other Makefiles, but didn't think that was applicable because I didn't consider my .env file a Makefile, but I guess it qualifies?

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough statement! I don't quite get it all though ... except that the question itself seems to involve that one string.  Please let me know if I actually oversimplified the matter in my answer

Comment: My first three bullet points are all I’m trying to do: expose the .env key-value pairs to make, parse them into variables, then use them to build/deploy. Your answer looks like it fixes my Regex, although I think Reinier Torenbeek’s comment/answer is exactly what I’m looking for. I can test it out this weekend. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: OK, that clarifies it. Yes, you can directly pull definitions from the shown `.env` file.  Added to answer

Comment: @twgardner2 : Yes, the format that you used for `.env` qualifies as valid `makefile` syntax. I converted my comment into an answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't fully get what is going on but I take it that you want to extract values from a string such as

```
SSH_CREDENTIALS=path/to/my/key ANOTHER_VAR=somethingelse YET_ANOTHER_VAR=yetanothersomething
```

That is, the path for `SSH_CREDENTIALS`.

If that's indeed the main objective, you're missing it by very little:

- That `.*` in the regex is *greedy* as it matches *as much as it can* so to still satisfy the regex.  Sicne it is followed by a lookahead for whitespace it will match up to *the very last* whitespace in the string.  Instead, you want to restrict it with `?`, so to use `.*?` which matches up to the *first* of the following pattern (space here)

  ```
  grep -o -P '(?<=SSH_CREDENTIALS=).*?(?=[[:space:]])'
  ```

  This works correctly in my test. Note that you can simply match non-space characters

  ```
  grep -o -P '(?<=SSH_CREDENTIALS=)\S+'
  ```
- I see a commented-out `sed` snippet and Perl is tagged. Regex with these tools is simpler with no need for lookaheads.  So pipe into

  ```
  perl -wne'/SSH_CREDENTIALS=(.*?)\s/; print $1'
  ```

  or, again, can match all consecutive non-space characters

  ```
  perl -wne'/SSH_CREDENTIALS=(\S+)/; print $1'
  ```

  I assumed that you don't need a newline. You can also use `[[:space:]]`.

See your favorite regex resource. In Perl that'd be tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and reference [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

---

With the clarification it appears that the whole objective is to pull variable definitions from another file into the Makefile. If the format of the file is exactly as shown, it can be directly [included](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) and thus provide those variable definitions. A simple example

A file **.env**

```
SSH_CREDENTIALS=path/to/my/key
ANOTHER_VAR=somethingelse
```

A **Makefile**

```
INCL = /usr/include/boost

include .env

fake: 
    @echo "a variable: $(INCL)"
    @echo "a variable from the included file:   $(SSH_CREDENTIALS)"
    @echo "another variable from included file: $(ANOTHER_VAR)"
```

With `make` we get the expected printout.

Keep in mind that `include` works with *a makefile*, so the file to include must satisfy that format.

Comment: I agree that `include .env` or equivalent looks like the 'obvious' way to solve the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for saying that -- the overall purpose escaped me at first, in spite of the detailed statement in the thorough and carefully written question.

Answer (score 3):

The contents of your `.env` file look like they could be included into you `makefile` directly, like this:

```
include .env
```

See [3.3 Including Other Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)